# Difference between fn() and fn.call() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, call

```
var tempFn = function(someText){
console.log(someText);
}

tempFn('siva');
// where I simply call the function with text 'siva'
```

vs.

```
tempFn.call(this,'siva');
// where I call the function using call method
```

What is the difference between these approaches?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation of `.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `call` form you are being explicit about the context that the function will be invoked with.

The context will determine what the value of `this` is when your function executes.

In your case, you are passing in `this` which would be the default anyway, so it's a no-op. Also, your `tempFn` function doesn't invoke the `this` keyword so it wouldn't matter anyway if you passed in a different scope.